# How can one increase the number of suggestions for the next words in Google Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, android-10, gboard, samsung-galaxy-s-9, productivity

I wonder how one can increase the number of suggestions for the next words in Google Keyboard. By default, only three words are shown (a, the and one in the screenshot below):

[image]

I use Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gboard does not have this feature, hence no setting for it. You can request Google to add this in the [Android help community](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/12731972/anyone-know-why-i-can-not-find-the-gboard-community-forum?hl=en&msgid=12991500) (Gboard does not have a dedicated forum).

Alternatively, use a keyboard that let's you do this (I am not aware of any but then I never looked for this feature)